# How can I return a &str from Strings in an enum in a method impl?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to return the name of the city/town/village as a reference to `str`. I can specify the lifetime in the implementation but specifying it also for the enum causes error as it has no reference declared.

```
enum CityType {
    City { name: String /* ... */ },
    Town { name: String /* ... */ },
    Village { name: String /* ... */ },
}

impl CityType {
    fn name(self) -> &str {
        match self {
            CityType::City { name } => &name,
            CityType::Town { name, .. } => &name,
            CityType::Village { name } => &name,
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bf361d3b76dae530a16adfa605b93ef2&version=stable)

Comment: What did you want `name` method to do exactly? It has multiple issues, and the answer may depend on your intention.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy in this case just return ref to the String. The issue is more general: how to return ref to a String which has no lifetime specifier as it lives as long as the enum does.

Comment: You need to (re)read [What is ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ownership-and-functions) chapter in the Rust book. `name(self)` takes ownership of the enum and the enum is deallocated upon the function return. You cannot return a reference to deallocated enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to return a city name **without** losing the object by consuming, you should write it as the following:

```
enum CityType {
    City { name: String },
    Town { name: String },
    Village { name: String },
}

impl CityType {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        match *self {
            CityType::City { ref name } => name,
            CityType::Town { ref name, .. } => name,
            CityType::Village { ref name } => name,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let city = CityType::City { name: "NY".to_owned() };
    println!("Name of the city: {}", city.name());
}
```

Explanation:

1. At first, your method's signature specifies that you **consume** the object:

   ```
   fn name(self) -> &str {
   ```

   After calling such a method, you will no longer be able to use the instance. If you want to read a string, you should accept a reference:

   ```
   fn name(&self) -> &str {
   ```

   This leads to another problem
2. `match` should work without moving an object, so here is `*`:

   ```
   match *self {
   ```
3. You should not move out from the enum's data, so the `ref` keyword helps

   ```
   CityType::City { ref name } => name,
   ```

   This keyword says that we must use pattern matching with a reference to value.
4. In the `main` you pass a `&str` but items in your enum are `String`, so this lead to incompatible types error. By calling `.to_owned()` method on a string reference you create a new `String` object from it:

   ```
   let city = CityType::City { name: "NY".to_owned() };
   ```

For your comment:

> The issue is more general: how to return ref to a String which has no lifetime specifier as it lives as long as the enum does.

In Rust you **can't** have a reference without a lifetime. Never. There are cases in which the compiler can deduce the lifetime for you, but there are also cases when it does it incorrectly or not what you expected. In this case, for example:

```
fn name(&self) -> &str {
```

There **are** lifetimes, the compiler treats this as the following:

```
fn name<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str {
```

Your references are bound to the same lifetime and they can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is exactly my use case.